# Holaplex Devnet GraphQL API?

Tags: metaplex, nft, devnet, metaplex-js

I am working on an NFT marketplace app that I found on GitHub.

The app uses the Holaplex GraphQL API for things like fetching NFTs from auction houses. And then using the Solana wallet-adapter for connecting to the user's wallet.

My question is, the Holaplex API is being init with `https://graph.holaplex.com/v1` that I believe is querying from Mainnet. I am working with things like the Metaplex JS SDK and want to create NFTs on Devnet and then use the Holaplex API to fetch those NFTs on the auction house on Devnet. However it seems Holaplex does not have a Devnet API? I looked around but could not find anything.

Can I use Holaplex API for querying data from Devnet? I really like their DX so would love to stick with using them if possible, but open to other solutions as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we recently deployed a devnet endpoint as well.

- https://graph.devnet.holaplex.tools/v1

Feel free to try it out using the playground at: https://graph.devnet.holaplex.tools/graphiql